# proving the set is closure and the fuction is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $A$ and $B$ and non-empty sets in a metric space $(X,d)$. Define
$$\rho (A,B) = \inf \{d(a,b) : a \in A, b \in B\}$$

(i) If $S$ is any non-empty subset of $(X,d)$, prove that $\bar{S} = \{x : x\in X \; \text{and} \; \rho(\{x\},S) = 0 \}$

My proof is that suppose $\bar{S} \ne  \{x : x\in X \; \text{and} \; \rho(\{x\},S) = 0 \}$. This implies that there exists $x$ such that $\rho(\{x\},S) > 0$, but $x$ is a limit point of $S$. We can define $0<r<\rho(\{x\},S)$, then $B_r(x) \cap S = \emptyset $, Hence we reach contradiction.

I am not sure if it is correct proof...

(ii) If $S$ is any non-empty subset of $(X,d)$ prove that the function $f:(X,d) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$f(x) = \rho(\{x\},S), x\in X$$
is continuous

Can you give some hints or how I should start this proof?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove f(x) is continuous, we consider two cases:

1. For $x \in \bar{S}$, we know f(x) = 0. So for any $\epsilon > 0$, and y, such that $\rho(x, y) \le \epsilon$, we know 
   $$|f(y) - f(x)| = \rho(\{y\}, S) \le \rho(y, x) < \epsilon $$
2. For $x \notin \bar{S}$, we know f(x) = d > 0. For any $d/2 > \epsilon > 0$, for y such that $\rho(y, x) < \epsilon$, we know $f(y) = \rho(\{y\}, S) > \rho(\{x\}, S) - \rho(x, y) = f(x) - \epsilon$, we also know
   $$f(y) = \rho(\{y\}, S) \le \rho(\{x\}, S) + \rho(x, y) = f(x) +\epsilon$$

Combing both
$$|f(y) - f(x)| \le \epsilon$$

Comment: Don't we have to show that $|x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$?
So, we also have to show that there exists $\delta$ for all $\epsilon >0$

Comment: @user1292919, here, we pick $\delta = \epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

For (i) what you have shown, correctly, is that $\bar S\supset \{x:\rho (\{x\},S)=0)\}.$ To finish, you need to show the reverse inclusion also, which should be easy.